# The task scheduling problem of Flink, in Flink, how to place subtasks in a slot of the specified task manager?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, apache-flink

Recently, I am studying the problem of task scheduling in Flink. My purpose is to schedule subtasks to a slot of the specified node according to my own needs by modifying some source codes of the scheduling part. Through remote debugging and checking the source code, I found the following method call stack, most of which I can't understand (the comments are a little less), especially in this method: `org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl#allocateMultiTaskSlot`. I guess the code that allocates slots to tasks is around here. Because it is too difficult to read the source code, I have to ask you for help. Of course, if there is a better way to achieve my needs, please specify one or two. Sincerely look forward to your reply! Thank you very much!!! 
The method call stack is as follows(The version of Flink I use is 1.11.1):
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster#startJobExecution`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster#resetAndStartScheduler`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster#startScheduling`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase#startScheduling`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler#startSchedulingInternal`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.strategy.EagerSchedulingStrategy#startScheduling` 
(This is like the method call chain of PipelinedRegionSchedulingStrategy class. In order to simply write it as the method call chain of EagerSchedulingStrategy class, it should have no effect)
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.strategy.EagerSchedulingStrategy#allocateSlotsAndDeploy`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler#allocateSlotsAndDeploy`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler#allocateSlots`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionSlotAllocator#allocateSlotsFor`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.SlotProviderStrategy.NormalSlotProviderStrategy#allocateSlot`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl#allocateSlot`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl#allocateSlotInternal`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl#internalAllocateSlot`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl#allocateSharedSlot`
`org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl#allocateMultiTaskSlot`
(I feel that this is the key to allocate slot for subtask, that is, execution vertex, but there is no comment, and I don't understand the process idea, so I can't understand it.)

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: For example, there are two taskmanagers, and each taskmanager has two slots. I want to implement the following requirements through code: put subtasks into the second slot of the second taskmanager I specify. In other words, I need to control which slot is assigned to subtask

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do this? The current scheduler doesn't offer this level of control, but its behavior can be modified to some extent. I'm trying to determine if the available controls will help you achieve your underlying goal(s).

Comment: Dear Anderson, thank you for your reply. I am a graduate student and my research direction is about Flink task scheduling, so I would like to ask you this question. What do you mean that its behavior can be modified to some extent?Do you mean to modify the source code to achieve this requirement.It will be very kind of you to help me. I am looking forward to your reply.

Comment: In general, the scheduler will try to co-locate data consumers with their producers. Sources don't have any a priori preferences, so they can be placed more or less anywhere. `cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots` will influence where the sources are scheduled, and the rest of the topology will follow.

Comment: That's not what I want. Through reading the source code, we can see the logic that when assigning slots to tasks, we will check whether there are currently available slots. If there are, we will score all available slots and select the slot with the highest score for allocation. If no slot is available, a new slot is requested from ResourceManager. Can I control the allocation of tasks and slots from these two directions?

Comment: When using Flink's `DefaultScheduler` then it is the component `ExecutionSlotAllocator` which is responsible for mapping tasks to slots. The only existing implementation `SlotSharingExecutionSlotAllocator` is responsible for sharing slots but you could also implement your own version of it.

Comment: Mr. Rohrmann, maybe because of the version, I didn't find the `SlotSharingExecutionSlotAllocator`. The version I used is 1.11.1. In addition, I found this method `org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.AnyMatchingSlotMatchingStrategy#findMatchingSlot`. It seems that I can only get the information of the slot, but not the information of the current task. And this method `org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.LocationPreferenceSlotSelectionStrategy#selectWitLocationPreference` is the same problem.

Comment: Hi, @penguin  Thank you for posting this great question. I am actually working on the similar problem of trying to control which task get to allocated to which task manager. I was wondering if you find some ways to do this. Thanks.