# Flink Task Manager Policy

Tags: apache-flink

I have a question regarding Apache Flink and how the framework chooses a task manager for its tasks. Let's consider a scenario with a 4 machine cluster(1 for JobManager, 3 for Task Managers). Now, I want to execute a simple job with 1 task(job requires resources from only one task manager). In order to execute the task, flink selects one of the available Task Managers. In case of task manager failure the job manager will choose one of the available task managers to continue(checkpoint case). My guess is that assigning tasks to task managers happens in a random fashion.

My question is, if it is possible to change somehow that policy and provide a mechanism(ex. a priority queue) to specify how tasks managers are selected. Also if the solution lies in modifying Flink source code, which classes could be responsible for such operations?

Comment: See the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/q/66409110/2000823 for some related discussion and pointers.